# I used ajax to make a sql statment but nothing seems to happen

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I put this code but nothing seems to happen when i check my mysql database

```
$.ajax("ajax.php?type=insert&giftcode="+newarray[$x]+"&winner=winner1");
```

and i ajax.php i put

```
require_once('setup.php'); //where i connect to the database 

if ($_GET['type']== "insert")
{

    $query='UPDATE prizes SET winner='+$_GET['winner'] +',time='+NOW()+',WHERE prizecode='+$_GET[giftcode]+'LIMIT 1';
    $insert_query = $db->query($query) ;
    checkDBError($insert_query);

    echo("something happened");

}
```

there is no problem with the database itself as there is no problem with connection as it works on different parts of the code but i can see what i did wrong

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer, but remember that PHP is executed before the javascript!

Comment: First of all: Sanitize your inputs or face SQL injections! Second: Have you checked, if your query returns an error?

Comment: @PRPGFerret Not when the PHP is executed via AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

You used + signs in your query. That's only valid in javascript. Please use points!
Also, the , sign before WHERE-statement is incorrect.

```
if($_GET['type']== "insert") {
    $query = 'UPDATE prizes SET winner = '.$_GET['winner'].', time = NOW() WHERE prizecode = '.$_GET['giftcode'].' LIMIT 1';
    $insert_query = $db->query($query) ;
    checkDBError($insert_query);

    echo("something happened");
}
```

Comment: thank you i didn't pay attention to the . thing ..i altered the code as you said but nothing seems to happen !!

Comment: I see you used this javascript code to call ajax script: $.ajax("ajax.php?type=insert&giftcode="+newarray[$x]+"&winner=winner1"); You can't use $x just in your javascript code. You should use <?php echo $x; ?> or use a javascript count

Comment: thank you for the answers ...actually i solved it .... its a rocky mistake 
 related to the quotes in this statement 
$query='UPDATE prizes SET winner="'.$_GET['winner'].'" WHERE prizecode="'.$_GET['giftcode'].'" LIMIT 1';